# WSL2 - Magento 2.4-Nginx - Css and Js Issue

Tags: nginx, magento2, wsl-2

I need suggestion with my magento setup.
I have windows 10 in my system. I am using wsl2 with nginx web server. I am trying to install magento2.4 but facing issue for loading css and js.
When hit js in new tab getting below error:

```
Requested path frontend/Magento/luma/en_TT/requirejs/require.js is wrong.
```

```
#1 Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run() called at [pub/static.php:13]
```

I have tried every solution from google but none help.
Plz help me here :(

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I'm having the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to run below command,

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade

php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy en_TT
```